# Parse.com retrieving count of last day sale in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, ngui

I'm trying to show count from a parse class into label but the following  error is occurring:

> "CompareBaseObjectsInternal can only be called from the main thread.
>   Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
>   Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function."

My code is given below. Can anyone help me?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> USQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Sales")
    .WhereEqualTo ("transactionType", "Purchase")
    .WhereGreaterThan ("createdAt",DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

USQuery.CountAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    int result=t.Result;
    labelUSSale.text=result.ToString();
});
```

Comment: Where is this code? The error is suggesting that you have it in a constructor and that instead you should move it to either the Start or Awake methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send value of NGUI label from main thread. Simple solution here would be waiting until "result" variable changes and then assigning label.text. I recommend looking into Tasks, there are much more friendly ways of controlling Parse.com queries.

https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#tasks

Try this:

```
IEnumerator GetSales()
{   
    int result = -1;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> USQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Sales").WhereEqualTo ("transactionType", "Purchase").WhereGreaterThan ("createdAt",DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

    USQuery.CountAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        result=t.Result;  
    });

    while (result == -1) yield return new WaitForSenOfFrame();
    labelUSSale.text=result.ToString();

}
```

Comment: thanks Greg Lucksek for your reply i was fixed this issue so early with the same approach you have mentioned.